# Get custom error (revert reason) in web3 app

Tags: web3js, custom-errors

Solidity has introduced Custom Error which is cheaper than requires (as I have read).

[image]

But when we get an error in web3(.js) functions like `estimateGas` we get `Returned error: execution reverted` as an error. No proper error to decode. I can see these errors in abi, but not sure how to detect in web3 app?

Comment: can you show your code pls? just looking at the custom errors, there's nothing defined that looks like it describes a gas problem so it seems reasonable to assume you don't have logic in your contract to detect that problem and revert with a custom error

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article in my blog about this topic.
[Using Web3.js to Parse Custom Error](https://blog.emn178.cc/en/post/using-web3-js-to-parse-custom-error/). It includes call, estimateGas and tx error. It should be helpful.

In your case, you can use this function to parse custom error.

```
import { Eip838ExecutionError } from 'web3';
import { decodeContractErrorData } from 'web3-eth-abi';

function parseInnerError(e, contract) {
  if (e?.innerError?.errorSignature) {
    return e.innerError;
  }

  if (!e.innerError) {
    if (e?.data?.data.startsWith('0x')) {
      e.innerError = new Eip838ExecutionError(e.data);
    }
  }
  if (e?.innerError?.data?.startsWith('0x')) {
    decodeContractErrorData(contract._errorsInterface, e.innerError);
  }
  return e.innerError;
}
```

And usage will be

```
try {
  await myContract.methods.sendWithError().estimateGas({ from });
} catch (e) {
  const innerError = parseInnerError(e, myContract);
}
```

Notice: RPC Node should also support custom error. For example, Arbitrum Goerli supports, but Ganache v2.5.4 not.

Tested at Web3.js v4.0.1 and Arbitrum Goerli.